# Fetching data from two mysql tables and showing it with php is showing incorrect order

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table structured below

transactions  table
[image]

invoicesq table

[image]

I want to show data from these two table to two tables in the front end. taking `invoice_id` and `customer_name` form alternative tables order by the `invoice_id`.

The connection between two table is reference numbers and more closely the `amount_paid` and `subtotal`

I have the following code:

```
$payment_reference = '71584705';



         $get_transaction_data = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE reference_no ='$payment_reference' ORDER BY id ASC" ) or die(mysqli_error($link));
         $get_transaction_data_two = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE reference_no = '$payment_reference' ORDER BY subtotal ASC" ) or die(mysqli_error($link));

        $get_invoice_data_details = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM invoicesq WHERE payment_payout_reference = '$payment_reference' ORDER BY invoice_id ASC");
        $get_transaction_data_one = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE reference_no = '$payment_reference'") or die(mysqli_error($link));
        $get_invoice_data_one = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM invoicesq WHERE payment_payout_reference = '$payment_reference' ORDER BY invoice_id ASC");

         $transaction_details = mysqli_fetch_array($get_transaction_data_two);
        ?> 
    <strong>Correct PaySheet summary</strong>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <th>Invoice</th>
                <th>Customer</th>
                <th>Sub Total</th>
                <th>Tax</th>
                <th>Holdback</th>
                <th>Total Paid</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php while($show_invoice_data = mysqli_fetch_array($get_invoice_data_details)){ 
                    $get_transaction = mysqli_fetch_array($get_transaction_data_one)
                    ?>

                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $show_invoice_data['invoice_id'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $get_transaction['customer_name'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $show_invoice_data['amount'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $show_invoice_data['tax'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $get_transaction['holdback'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $show_invoice_data['amount_paid'];?></td>


                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
            </tbody>    
            </table>
        <h3><h4>Pay Sheet Summary</h4></h3> 
        <table>
            <thead>
                <th>Invoice ID</th>
                <th>Customer Name</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Amount Paid</th>
                <th>Tax</th>

            </thead>
            <tbody>

                <?php

                 while($show_transactions_data = mysqli_fetch_array($get_transaction_data)) {

                    $print_invoice = mysqli_fetch_array($get_invoice_data_one);


                    ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $print_invoice['invoice_id'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $show_transactions_data['customer_name'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $show_transactions_data['subtotal'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $show_transactions_data['total'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $show_transactions_data['tax'];?></td>

                </tr>
                <?php } 


                ?>
            </tbody>    


        </table>
```

It is showing mismatched at sorting 
[image]

Please help me to make it correct. Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use `ORDER BY` clause when getting data from database

Comment: ORDER BY works for invoice_id in correct Paysheet summary but How i will match invoice_id and name as this two are from opposite tables.

Comment: You can sort an array

Comment: Please notice that each concurrently running MySQL query requires its own separate `$link` object.

Answer (score -1):

Try Selecting by with single query

```
$get_transaction_data_two = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM transactions INNER  JOIN invoicesq ON payment_payout_reference = reference_no  WHERE reference_no = '$payment_reference' ORDER BY subtotal ASC" ) or die(mysqli_error($link));
$transaction_details = mysqli_fetch_array($get_transaction_data_two);
```